# Adding an array to an existing csv file

Tags: arrays, pandas, csv, append

I know this question was already asked, but after trying most of the accepted answer none of them seems to work with my simple task...

I have a csv file as follow:

```
Date,Median
2000-01-31,9
2000-02-28,8
2000-03-31,7
2000-04-30,6
2000-05-31,5
2000-06-30,4
2000-07-31,3
2000-08-31,2
2000-09-30,1
2000-10-31,0
2000-11-30,11
2000-12-31,12
```

and then an array:

```
[0.1829   0.171349 0.162461 0.152306 0.14122  0.137749 0.138802 0.150315
 0.156784 0.168297 0.180634 0.187241]
```

I wish to append this array as a third column to the csv file to get the following output:

```
Date,Median,Median2
2000-01-31,9,0.1829
2000-02-28,8,0.171349
2000-03-31,7,0.162461
2000-04-30,6,0.152306
2000-05-31,5,0.14122
2000-06-30,4,0.137749
2000-07-31,3,0.138802
2000-08-31,2,0.150315
2000-09-30,1,0.156784
2000-10-31,0,0.168297
2000-11-30,11,0.180634
2000-12-31,12,0.187241
```

I tried most of the answer related to this kind of question but I did not succeed to make them work..here is the last code I tried, using pandas that looks easier but it does not work:

```
data=pd.read_csv("data_1.csv",sep=',')
array_transpose = array.reshape((-1, 1)) #in order to transpose the array
data['Median2'] = data[array_transpose]
data.to_csv('output.csv')
```

which produce the following error:

```
KeyError: '[0.1829   0.171349 0.162461 0.152306 0.14122  0.137749 0.138802   0.150315\n 0.156784 0.168297 0.180634 0.187241] not in index'
```

How to append this array to my csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need `reshape`

```
data=pd.read_csv("data_1.csv",sep=',')
data['Median2'] = array
data.to_csv('output.csv')
```